# Reputation decreased for a question I was not involved in

Tags: support, bug, reputation

Today I was surprised to see my reputation on SO degraded by `-2` for a question that I was not active at at all:

```
-2   4 hours ago   removed   Writing Automated Unix Script (Using SSH and FTP)
```

The question does not exist anymore and I can not remember that I opened or closed such a question. And I can not even search for that question as it was obviously removed.

So is this a bug I'm facing? If yes, what can I do to get my precious 2 reputation points back?

Comment: Most likely you were awarded those 2 points for an accepted edit, then the question/answer was removed

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. I can't remeber every edit :). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you made an edit on that question (or one of it's answers) and since they eventually got deleted the 2 rep you got from the edit went with them.

The only way to find out for sure is to get a 10k user or mod to check for you.

Comment: The relevant question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15252859/writing-automated-unix-script-using-ssh-and-ftp) (10k) and there was indeed an approved suggested edit by Michael that is now deleted.

Comment: Thank you for checking @sth :)

Answer (score 2):

This means that you made an edit on the question or an answer to that question, and the edit was accepted, giving you +2 reputation.

The question was deleted later, and you lost that reputation. No biggie :)